# Is there a function for multivariate data analysis in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataframe with multiple variables and would like to plot the multi-variate relationships on a grid of plots.
Here is the dataframe:

df=pd.DataFrame({'Year':[2005,2005,2005,2005,2006,2006,2006,2006,2007,2007,2007,2007,2008,2008,2008,2008],'Month': ['June', 'June','July', 'July','June', 'June','July', 'July','June', 'June','July', 'July','June', 'June','July', 'July'], 'Gate': ['A','B', 'A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B',], 'Passengers':[20000, 30000,25000,30000,20000, 25000, 25000,30000,30000,35000,20000,15000,20000,25000,15000,15000]})

I would like to plot the variation (a histogram) of passengers (y-axis) with the years (x-axis) for each month and each gate. For example, one of the subplots will show the passengers vs the years for the month of June at gate A.

Answer (score 0):

You have a little bit wrong data. You override it.

2005:

June->A->20000

July->B->30000

June->A->25000

July->B->30000

As you can see line 1 and 3 have different numbers for the same month.
 I fixed it for myself.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'Year':[2005,2005,2005,2005,2006,2006,2006,2006,2007,2007,2007,2007,2008,2008,2008,2008],
                 'Month': ['June', 'July','June', 'July','June', 'July','June', 'July','June', 'July','June', 'July','June', 'July','June', 'July',], 
                 'Gate': ['A','B', 'B','A','A','B', 'B','A','A','B', 'B','A','A','B', 'B','A',], 
                 'Passengers':[20000, 30000,25000,30000,20000, 25000, 25000,30000,30000,35000,20000,15000,20000,25000,15000,15000]})

df.pivot_table('Passengers',['Year','Gate','Month'])
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

df.pivot_table('Passengers',index='Year',columns=['Gate','Month']).plot()
plt.ylabel('number of passengers')
```

I think it will be enough.

Comment: The code plots all in one single plot. However, I would like to have each month,gate combination separately as part of a grid plot. As well the years are repeated on the x axis. There is two of 2005 and two of 2006, etc.. I have edited the data frame you were right.

Comment: I don't know.
Try this:

df.pivot_table('Passengers',index=['Month','Year'],columns=['Month','Gate']).plot()

plt.gca().set_xticklabels(['2005', '2006', '2007', '2008','2005', '2006', '2007', '2008'])

plt.ylabel('number of passengers')